# Ruby on Rails 3 or ASP .NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ruby-on-rails-3

This is my question, should learn Ruby on Rails 3 or ASP .NET MVC 4 in term of jobs security and freelance. I live in the East Coast (NYC, NJ, CT).

Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: For jobs security and freelance learn and be proficient in both.

Comment: I think success has a lot more to do with doing something you love, rather than picking a path based on the number of theoretical opportunities. Maybe you could expand the question to include some background. If your question had a definitive answer, either MVC4 or Ruby on Rails would not exist, because everyone would adopt the other.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, it's all about preference. Personally, I like Ruby as a language and the Rails framework compliments it very well. I know of many companies on the East Coast that are actively looking for Ruby developers.

The community for Ruby is very active, passionate and nice. I know of a few developers that have done the switch from .NET to Ruby and they couldn't be happier.

I'm not saying .NET is bad or anything of that sort. Maybe someone else can give you their insight on .NET area.

One piece of advice is that you shouldn't just stick to one specific language or framework. Rails is just one of many frameworks that Ruby has to offer. Look into Sinatra and Padrino. Also, it's always good to learn about different languages as you can compliment your knowledge. Erlang, Scala, and Javascript are very interesting languages that you should take your time to look into.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Leo for you comment. I will take your advise.

Comment: If you like his answer, press the Up arrow next to it :)

Comment: .NET is going to be more relevant in corporate & government & military settings. At the end of the day though, there are probably plenty of companies using RoR.